# Asymptotic expansion for $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{- R x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

How do I get the asymptotic expansion for the integral

$$ I(R) = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{- R x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx,$$

when $R \to +\infty$?

I was able to relate this integral to the Dawson function $F(x)$,
so that

$$ I(R) = \frac 2 {\sqrt R} F(\sqrt R) ,$$

and from there I was able to 
get the

$$ I(R) = \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{2R^2} + \ldots, ~~~ {\rm as}~~~ R\to +\infty.$$

But what is the simplest way to get this directly from the original integral?

Simple integration by parts does not seem to do the trick here.

Comment: Use [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: How about using $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k-1/2}{k} x^k$.

Comment: Ok tnx, guys! @RiverLi ok this is quite simple and straightforward. Tnx a bunch!